# how to identify the difference between two date time in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, date, datediff, date-difference

I want to identify the working hours between the below two different dates in bash?

```
date1="2020-04-17 20:09:42"
date2="2020-04-28 20:40:10"

difference= <should be in hours>
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Define *working hours* in your question. Do you have access to GNU date command?